# How do I animate custom properties on a SCNNode?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, scenekit

I have an object that during initialisation create a geometry.

```
class Helix {
    var width: GLfloat      // x
    var height: GLfloat     // y
    var depth: GLfloat      // z
    var radius: GLfloat
    var pitchInherent: GLfloat
    var pitchCurrent: GLfloat
    /* Other SceneKit related properties used later */
    init(width: Float, height: Float, depth: Float) {
        /* Geometry logic */
        geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource], elements: [element])
    }
    func getNode() -> SCNNode {
        return SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    }
}
```

Then inside my view controller, I add it to the node tree.

```
let scene = SCNScene()
let helix = Helix(width: 30, height: 30, depth: 30)
let helixNode = helix.getNode()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(helixNode)
```

I want to animate the `pitchCurrent` property. In the `Objective-C` world when customising `CALayer` objects, I used to designate those properties that I wanted to animate as `dynamic` and assigned a listener for the appropriate `key`. How should I do this in this context?

Comment: My fear is that I probably have to redo the whole vertex array for each frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuilding a vertex array per frame isn't that bad. Re-uploading it to the GPU each frame, however, will probably not result in performance that brightens your day.

Instead, I'd recommend using [shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/) to customize your geometry in the GPU's vertex stage. (Be sure to hit the "More" link at the top of that page for a thorough discussion.) You can even combine this with your custom `Helix` class to make changing your width/radius/pitch/etc parameters from Swift nice and easy — SceneKit objects that implement `SCNShadable` automatically use KVO to let you treat GLSL uniforms as class properties.

To do this, you'd first need to refactor so that `Helix` subclasses `SCNGeometry` or `SCNNode`, and then, like in the `CALayer` case, declare your properties as `dynamic`.

Then, create a GLSL snippet that does the geometry customization:

```
// declare uniforms whose names match your class' dynamic properties
uniform float width;
uniform float height;
// etc

// do your geometry math 
_geometry.position = /* Geometry logic */
```

Finally, assign this snippet to the `shaderModifiers` for your node, using the `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry` entry point:

```
let shader = "all that GLSL stuff above" // or better, load it from a file
geometry.shaderModifiers = [ SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry: shader ]
```

At this point, you should be able to create an instance of your custom Helix node/geometry and use any of SceneKit's animation tricks to animate its `width`, `height`, etc properties.

Comment: This certainly opens up a whole new area of stuff I need to figure out. It'll take awhile for me to do that, so for the time being, thanks! I'll come back with more details if need be :)

Comment: please note that your custom properties do not necessarily have to be `dynamic`. It's just that `SCNNode` and `SCNGeometry` are key-value coding compliant container classes (just like `CALayer`) and allow you to use KVC for arbitrary keys.